# Xcode Project with speech-recognition works on one computer, but not on others

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition

I am working on a project that involves speech-recognition for an ios app and prints everything that is being said to the screen. I am using the speech library and it works on my computer, but when my colleague opens the project in his computer the program compiles, but the speech-recognition doesn't print anything. Does anyone know why this would happen?

I have been trying to solve this issue for hours, but can't find anything about it online. I also tried reinstalling Xcode in his computer, but it didn't work either.

Here is my code:

```swift
import UIKit
import Speech

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var activateBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    private var speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale:Locale.init(identifier:"en-Us"))//1
    private var recognitionRequest: SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?
    private var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?
    private var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    var lang:String = "en-US"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        activateBtn.isEnabled = false //2
        speechRecognizer?.delegate = self as? SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate//3
        speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale:Locale.init(identifier: lang))
        SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization{ (authStatus) in //4
            var isButtonEnabled = false

            switch authStatus{//5
            case .authorized:
                isButtonEnabled = true
            case .denied:
                isButtonEnabled = false
                print("User denied access to speech recognition")
            case .restricted:
                isButtonEnabled = false
                print("Speech recognition restricted on this device")
            case .notDetermined:
                isButtonEnabled = false
                print("Speech recognition not yet authorized")
            }
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation(){
                self.activateBtn.isEnabled = isButtonEnabled
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func activateMic(_ sender: Any) {
        print("activateMic")
        speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale:Locale.init(identifier:lang))

        if audioEngine.isRunning{
            audioEngine.stop()
            recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
            activateBtn.isEnabled = false
            activateBtn.setTitle("Start Recording", for: .normal)
        }else{
            startRecording()
            activateBtn.setTitle("Stop Recording", for: .normal)
        }
    }

    func startRecording() {
        print("Start Recording")

        if recognitionTask != nil {
            recognitionTask?.cancel()
            recognitionTask = nil
        }

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.record)
            try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.measurement)
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
        }

        recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

        let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode

        guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
            fatalError("Unable to create an SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object")
        }

        recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true

        recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in

            var isFinal = false

            if result != nil {

                self.textView?.text = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString

                //Added stop after the word "stop" is part of the string
                if (((result?.bestTranscription.formattedString)?.contains("stop"))!) {
                    self.audioEngine.stop()
                }

                isFinal = (result?.isFinal)!
            }

            if error != nil || isFinal {
                self.audioEngine.stop()
                inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)

                self.recognitionRequest = nil
                self.recognitionTask = nil

                self.activateBtn.isEnabled = true
            }
        })

        let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
        inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, when) in
            self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
        }

        audioEngine.prepare()

        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
            print("audioEngine couldn't start because of an error.")
        }

        textView?.text = "Say something, I'm listening!"
    }

    func speechRecognizer(_ speechRecognizer: SFSpeechRecognizer, availabilityDidChange available: Bool) {
        print("Speech Recognizer")
        if available {
            activateBtn.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            activateBtn.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Show. Your. Code.

Comment: Ok. Just added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key word in your question is probably "computer". Speech recognition doesn't necessarily work in a simulator. Your friend needs to run your code on a *device*.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to work in his simulator though? We just tried running it on several other computers and half of them would work and the other half wouldn't. Is this just like a hit and miss and if it doesn't work on one then there is nothing we can do?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing you can do. I'm surprised to hear that it _ever_ works in the simulator. I've never gotten speech recognition to work anywhere except on a device. Of course it may be that your friend has no microphone permission for the Simulator, but I don't think it's that simple. Basically this is a device-only technology. There are lots of those.

Comment: Good to know, I guess we will start to do our testing on an actual device instead and see how it goes. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It’s very easy to distribute your app to someone else’s device for testing — much easier than making someone run your app via Xcode. So it’s a better strategy in any case.